# Android ESC W print area

Tags: android, printing, thermal-printer, escpos

I have a Datecs DPP-450 ESC POS thermal printer, which comes with an API.

I can successfully print over Bluetooth, since the API provides simple codes for connecting, printing texts and borders, but I am unable to set page height bigger than 2000+ ( dots I think ). I am printing invoices and I need height bigger than 2000. I have search on the internet and found :

> ESC W xL xH yL yH dxL dxH dyL dyH.
>
> Set printing area in page mode
>
> [Range] 0≤ xL xH yL yH dxL dxH dyL dyH ≤255 (except  dxL=dxH=0 or dyL=dyH=0 )
>
> [Description] The horizontal starting position, vertical starting position, printing area width, and printing area height are defined as x0, y0, dx, dy, respectively.
>   Each setting for the printable area is calculated as follow:
>
> x0 = [(xL + xH x 256) x (horizontal motion unit)]
>
> y0 = [(yL + yH x 256) x (vertical motion unit)]
>
> dx = [(dxL + dxH x 256) x (horizontal motion unit)]
>
> dy = [(dyL + dyH x 256) x (vertical motion unit)]

, but can't manage to make it work.

Not much code to show, I have tried :

```
printer.reset();
printer.write(new byte[]{0x1B});
printer.write(new byte[]{0x57});
printer.write(new byte[]{0});  OR new byte[]{0x30}
printer.write(new byte[]{0});  OR new byte[]{0x30}
printer.write(new byte[]{0});  OR new byte[]{0x30}
printer.write(new byte[]{0});  OR new byte[]{0x30}
printer.write(new byte[]{64}); OR new byte[]{0x36, 0x34}
printer.write(new byte[]{3});  OR new byte[]{0x33}
printer.write(new byte[]{96}); OR new byte[]{0x39, 0x36}
printer.write(new byte[]{11}); OR new byte[]{0x31, 0x31}
printer.selectPageMode();  // make printer enter PAGE MODE
```

Any ideas of correct way to get a height around 5000 ? As a workaround I can print piece by piece but I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  What does printer.write(new byte[]{0});  OR new byte[]{0x30} mean?  Does it send 0x00 or 0x30 to the printer?  Please be more precise....

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

Maximum size for printing in Page Mode is 832x1732 dots (47th command explanation) acording documentation: [dpp450.pdf](http://www.datecsbrasil.com.br/downloads/16022016171309ingles_manual_programador_dpp450.pdf)

Im working in a DPP-450 project too, some advanced things are really hard to discover, the API does not cover everything, if you need something more advanced you will need to use "byte-to-byte" commands, I guess.

Comment: I have returned the printer. I asked for support for setting a bigger height in page mode and to personalize character size. With small text it was unreadable, medium made invoices have 0.5m height. Have you managed to set a different height and character size ?

Comment: With basic configuration I can print text around 1 cm height, it depends what font you used. Fonts can be "uploaded" to printer, I did not try it yet, because I need an cable usb 10 pin <> serial I guess. Im using this printer to print labels with 50mm height, I dont have the same problem of you...If you want I can send to you by email some examples of android apps for this printer, I got with brazilian vendor this week. Im using the printer API with Ionic, I am not using native android development, but functions calls are the same since the API is written in java...

Comment: let me know your email to send the files.

Comment: I have the documentation. But in examples by default I can use printTaggedText (if I remember the correct function) which has parameters {s} - small, nothing - normal, {h} - high, {w} - wide. I would need a character size between {s} and normal to print invoices. With small text, older people would have problems reading it. With normal text, a 20 position invoice would exceed 0.5 meters. I have returned the printer and won't use it again because I was dissapointed by the support team. I am not developing something expensive on products that do not offer support.